# get all the tracks from playlist Spotify

Tags: ios, spotify

I was able to get all the playlist of users using spotify ios sdk, this is my code.

```
[SPTPlaylistList playlistsForUserWithSession:session callback:^(NSError *error, id object) {
    SPTListPage *pl= object;
    NSLog(@"%@",pl.items);
}];
```

But I am not sure now How to get all the tracks of these playlists. any help?

Answer (score 4):

Because this Spotify ios SDK v10beta is new and with many incomplete tasks, to access and be able to play all tracks in your playlists you have to run through many blocks.

First I would recommend to get the first SPTListPage object of all the playlists:

```
-(void)getFirstPlaylistPage
{
[SPTPlaylistList playlistsForUserWithSession:[SPTAuth defaultInstance].session callback:^(NSError *error, SPTListPage *playlistsPage) {
    if (error != nil) {
        NSLog(@"*** Getting playlists got error: %@", error);
        return;
    }
    if (playlistsPage==nil) {
        NSLog(@"*** No playlists were found for logged in user. ***");
        return;
    }

    [self getFullPlaylistPage:playlistsPage];
}];
```

}

Then, merge all SPTListPage objects into one:

```
-(void)getFullPlaylistPage:(SPTListPage*)listPage {

if (listPage.hasNextPage) {
    [listPage requestNextPageWithSession:[SPTAuth defaultInstance].session callback:^(NSError *error, SPTListPage* playlistPage) {
        if (error != nil) {
            NSLog(@"*** Getting playlist page got error: %@", error);
            return;
        }

        listPage = [listPage pageByAppendingPage:playlistPage];
        [self getFullPlaylistPage:listPage];
    }];
} else {

    NSMutableArray* playlist = [[NSMutableArray alloc]init];
    [self convertPlaylists:listPage arrayOfPlaylistSnapshots:playlist positionInListPage:0];
}
}
```

Now, SPTListPage contains SPTPartialPlaylist objects, which do not contain all the info of the playlists, so we need to convert it to SPTPlaylistSnapshot object:

```
-(void)convertPlaylists:(SPTListPage*)playlistPage arrayOfPlaylistSnapshots:(NSMutableArray*)playlist positionInListPage:(NSInteger)position
{    
    if (playlistPage.items.count > position) {
        SPTPartialPlaylist* userPlaylist = playlistPage.items[position];
        [SPTPlaylistSnapshot playlistWithURI:userPlaylist.uri session:[SPTAuth defaultInstance].session callback:^(NSError *error, SPTPlaylistSnapshot* playablePlaylist) {

            if (error != nil) {
                NSLog(@"*** Getting playlists got error: %@", error);
                return;
            }

            if(!playablePlaylist){
                NSLog(@"PlaylistSnapshot from call back is nil");
                return;
            }

            [playlist addObject:playablePlaylist];
            [self convertPlaylists:playlistPage arrayOfPlaylistSnapshots:playlist positionInListPage:position+1];

        }];

    } else {
    // send your array of playlists somewhere example:
     [self addSongs];
    }
    }
```

Now you can access all the playlists and all the songs in them with a simple loop-through.
I hope spotify will improve here as it is not how it supposed to be. Come on,Spotify!

Comment: how to return all songs of playlist?

Answer (score 3):

Using Swift3:

After authentication, define a playlist request , like this:

```
let playListRequest = try! SPTPlaylistList.createRequestForGettingPlaylists(forUser: userName, withAccessToken: token)
```

I use alamofire to post this request:

```
Alamofire.request(playListRequest)
        .response { response in


        let list = try! SPTPlaylistList(from: response.data, with: response.response)

        for playList in list.items  {
            if let playlist = playList as? SPTPartialPlaylist {
                print( playlist.name ) // playlist name
                print( playlist.uri)    // playlist uri

                let stringFromUrl =  playlist.uri.absoluteString
                let uri = URL(string: stringFromUrl)
                // use SPTPlaylistSnapshot to get all the playlists
                SPTPlaylistSnapshot.playlist(withURI: uri, accessToken: token!) { (error, snap) in
                    if let s = snap as? SPTPlaylistSnapshot {
                        // get the tracks for each playlist
                        print(s.name) 

                        for track in s.firstTrackPage.items {
                            if let thistrack = track as? SPTPlaylistTrack {

                                print(thistrack.name)

                            }
                        }
                    }


                }
            }
        }
}
```

Comment: I want to hug you. Searching for an example in the hopes of finding one in objective-c for a deprecated version of the spotify api, I see "Using Swift3:" as I scroll down... And then try it... And it works. Thank you.